# Is there a way to make vertices not move?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, vertices

I have made a robot character, and I made a cut in his arm so that there could be two different materials.

[image: This is the cut loop cut I made in his arm]

The problem is that when I move the arm, now this new cut acts as new vertices (like another elbow) and now there are too many joints in the arm. Is there a way to make these vertices stiff?

[image: The arm bends in three joints]

Because this description probably makes no sense, I will post the Blend file for you guys to check out. (Because they take so long to upload it won't be here right away)

Comment: For uploading files please use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ it will be fast and simple. As to your question - the only way to "stop" vertices from moving in different ways is to move them in the same way, i.e. add them to the same group and weight paint them the same as you use armature deforming.

Comment: @MrZak I am uploading it to the blend exchange, and it is still at 0% Otherwise, I will try assigning the vertex groups